# Display Name in Table with starting two character

Tags: c#

I want to display short name in starting of a table in C#- just like

Name -Rashid Ahmad

Short Name- RA

any one have idea how to do it in C#

Comment: sounds like you didnt even try....

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0):

You could split it on  and take the first character of the first and last word like this:

```
string name = "Rashid Ahmad";
string shortName = "";
var splits = name.Split( ' ' );
shortName += splits.First()[0];
shortName += splits.Last()[0];
Console.WriteLine(shortName);//Outputs RA
```

I would make it into a method with a bit more validation though:

```
private static string GetShortName( string name )
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( name ) )
    {
        return "";
    }
    string shortName = "";
    var splits = name.Split(' ');
    shortName += splits.First()[0];
    shortName += splits.Last()[0];
    return shortName;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
string shortName = GetShortName( "Rashid Ahmad" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by splitting the string into arrays and get the first character of the resulting array:

```
string strInput = "Rashid Ahmad";
string[] strArray = strInput.Split(' ').ToArray();
string strResult = strArray[0][0] + strArray[1][0].ToString();
```

Output:

```
RA
```

Answer (score 0):

One Liner:

```
var result = string.Join(string.Empty, "Rashid Ahmed".Split(' ').Select(x => x[0]));
```